# add a context menu option in nautilus por pdf files

Tags: nautilus, context-menu

I have a handy bash file to convert pdf files to jpg. I'd like to have an option in nautilus so that when I right-click on a pdf file I get the option to create the corresponding jpg file using that script.

Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want Nautilus Actions - extension for Nautilus that does exactly this. Everything what follows is taken from https://www.howtogeek.com/116807/how-to-easily-add-custom-right-click-options-to-ubuntus-file-manager/.

First, install package nautilus-actions:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-actions
```

Quit nautilus:

```
nautilus -q
```

Then open Nautilus-Action Configuration Tool. It should be straightforward from there.

Hope this helps you, comment if you have any questions